# How to reject or accept an incoming call to my GSM modem using AT commands in Python?

Tags: python, gsm, at-command, pyserial, modem

I've wrote the below Python program to wait for incoming calls and accept or reject them. Based on [this](http://www.zeeman.de/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/ubinetics-at-command-set.pdf) document and [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Cellular%20Modules/AT_Commands_Reference_Guide_r0.pdf) document, the appropriate AT commands to accept an incoming call is `ATA` or `ATS0` or `ATS0<n>`. And also the appropriate commands to reject the incoming call is `ATH` or `AT H`.

I tried all the above commands, but the incoming call neither answered nor rejected!

**My Python program :**

```
import time
import serial

phone = serial.Serial("COM10",  115200, timeout=5)

try:
    time.sleep(1)

    while(1):
        x = phone.readline()
        print(x)
        if (x == b'RING\r\n'):
            phone.write(b'AT H') # I replaced this 'AT H' with all the above
                                 # commands, but nothing changed about the
                                 # incoming call. It always ringing.
            time.sleep(2)

finally:
    phone.close()
```

**Results for `AT H`:**

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
b''
b''
b'\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'AT H\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'AT H\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'AT H\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'AT H\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
```

**Results for `ATH`:**

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
b''
b''
b''
b'\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'ATH\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'ATH\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'ATH\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
```

**Results for `ATA`:**

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
b''
b''
b''
b'\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'ATA\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'ATA\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'ATA\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
```

**Results for `ATS0`:**

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
b''
b''
b''
b'\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'ATS0\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
b'ATS0\r\n'
b'RING\r\n'
```

As you see above, the GSM modem regardless of the AT command that I send to it, continue to ringing. What's wrong about my program?

*Note that my modem is a [D-Link DWM-156](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/product/dwm-156-3-75-hsupa-usb-adapter) and I can send SMS or make a call successfully using it in Python.*
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of GSM module you have?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور It's a [D-Link DWM-156](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/product/dwm-156-3-75-hsupa-usb-adapter).

Comment: then you should refer to its manual for proper AT commands!...Let me check it out

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Are AT-Commands different per modem types? I was thought those are standardized for all the GSM modems. Am I wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but you, yourself, provided for us different AT commands for samething, nop?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Nope, I don't. `ATA` is "Answer", `ATS0` is "Automatic Answer" and  `ATS0<n>` is "Answer after n rings."

Comment: Ok...another thing, `AT` commands should end with **CR**, right?...I see you have like `\r\n` not `\r`...?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور May I ask you to post this last comment as an answer? :)

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81065/discussion-between-abraham-and-khalil-ammour--) please.

Comment: Concerning your voice issue, you may post it as a new question and will try to find answers for it as well..:)

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Thank you dear Khalil. Okay, I'll post it as a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to the end of each `AT` command a **CR** to make it a valid `AT` command

Answer (score 3):

We can't reject the incoming call directly. To reject incoming Calls, We should configure the Voice hang up control command,

AT+CVHU  (command for voice hang up).

ATH command is depends on AT+CVHU.

Answer (score 1):

```
phone = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

try:
    time.sleep(1)

    while(1):
        x = phone.readline()
        print(x)
        if (x == b'RING\r\n'):
            phone.write('ATH'+'\r\n') 
            time.sleep(2)

finally:
    phone.close()
```